# How does postgres 11+ maintain default value after the default is dropped?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Given the following commands:

```
create table foo(id serial primary key);
insert into foo values (1), (2), (3), (4);
alter table foo add column bar integer not null default 10;
alter table foo alter column bar drop default;
```

When I execute `select * from foo;` I get:

```
 id | bar 
----+------
  1 |  10 
  2 |  10 
  3 |  10 
  4 |  10
```

How is this possible if starting with postgresql 11+, it evaluates not null defaults lazily?

Comment: From here [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-altertable.html):"When a column is added with ADD COLUMN and a non-volatile DEFAULT is specified, the default is evaluated at the time of the statement and the result stored in the table's metadata. That value will be used for the column for all existing rows."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column defaults are stored in the system catalog `pg_attrdef`, while column definitions are stored in `pg_attribute`. If you drop the default value, the `pg_attrdef` row is deleted, but the `pg_attribute` row isn't.

The secret behind what you observe is that the “missing attribute value” is stored in `pg_attribute`, so it is not affected:

```
SELECT attmissingval
FROM pg_attribute
WHERE attrelid = 'foo'::regclass
  AND attname = 'bar';

 attmissingval 
═══════════════
 {10}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down each alter statement:

```
alter table foo add column bar integer not null default 10
```

This adds the new column, and due to `not null default 10`, each row is given `10` for the column value.

At this point, all *existing* rows have `10` and all *future* rows will be given `10` if a value is not provided on insert.

```
alter table foo alter column bar drop default
```

This does not affect existing rows. It only affects *future* rows being inserted, now *requiring* a value because the constraint `not null` remains, but the default does not.

Comment: OP asks the question because from 11 Postgres has stopped rewriting existing rows when adding a defaulted column, so their question is the underlying mechanism which allows postgres to remember that a default value was set on those columns even though the rows were never updated, and the defaulting was removed.